# Powershell/Bat file Merger

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to scripting Powershell but have a reasonable experience with writing Bat files.

I have a powershell script that unzips a bat, a reg file and a msi, the powershell script then launches the bat file, I dont think this is the best way to do it, is there a way to just get the powershell script to unzip and then install the msi and reg files rather than running a seperate bat file?

Here are the 2 files:

BAT:

```
@echo off

echo Installing Teamviewer, please wait...
msiexec /qn /i "C:\Temp\TeamViewer.msi" /passive
echo[
regedit /s C:\Temp\TeamViewer_Settings.reg
Pause
exit
```

PS:

```
$BackUpPath = "C:\Temp\Install.zip"

$Destination = "C:\Temp"

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

[io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory($BackUpPath, $destination)

Start-Process "C:\Temp\installer.bat"
```

Is there a way to just run the powershell script and extract and install the required files?

Many thanks and be kind, this is my first Powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `start-process` to run the bat file so just use the same to run the `msi` file instead.
Since there isnt a powershell cmdlet to import regitry files you can use `regedit.exe` to import the reg file.

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList "/qn /i 'C:\Temp\TeamViewer.msi' /passive" -Wait 
Start-Process -Filepath 'regedit.exe' -ArgumentList "/s 'C:\Temp\TeamViewer_Settings.reg'"
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, thank you! That makes sense! Not sure why I couldnt figure that out alone.
I'm now receiving this error:
   File C:\Temp\tps.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Temp\tps.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this 
script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see 
about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

How do I sign the script so that it runs?

Comment: welcome Mark....the error suggests that the execution policy on your computer is set to `allsigned` which means every ps script will need to be signed before you can execute it....while this is the safest option most people set the execution policy to  `remotesigned`.. ...check this link for more details `https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396`...note: .launch powershell as an administrator

Comment: also this link on how to sign scripts.....`https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.04.powershell.aspx`

Comment: Thank you Kiran :)
You've been a big help.